# cakephp - Followers relationship

Tags: cakephp

Im trying to create a User Connections relationship:

1. Following (people im following).
2. Followers (people who follows me).

My question:

It is a self-relationship? How do I define this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Untested, but somethinglike this should work:

```
class User extends AppModel {
  var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Friend' => array(
      'className' => 'User',
      'joinTable' => 'friends',
      'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
      'associationForeignKey' => 'friend_id',
    ),
    'Follower' => array(
      'className' => 'User',
      'joinTable' => 'followers',
      'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
      'associationForeignKey' => 'follower_id',
    )
  );
}
```

Where you've got your standard users table, plus a friends table with user_id and friend_id fields, and a followers table with user_id and follower_id fields.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a HABTM relationship. Although you will be referring twice to the same model (User) instead to two separate ones form the join-table.

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `users`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `username` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `password` VARCHAR(100) NULL ,
  `email` VARCHAR(100) NULL ,
  `created` DATETIME NULL ,
  `modified` DATETIME NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `followers_users`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `followers_users` (
  `user_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `follower_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`, `follower_id`) ,
  INDEX `fk_followers_users_users1` (`follower_id` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_followers_users_users`
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id` )
    REFERENCES `users` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_followers_users_users1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`follower_id` )
    REFERENCES `users` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

You can create a FollowersController that extends UsersController and then further define the relationship in the follower model. So you would actually have a model to refer back to.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Well, after looking at your question again it wouldn't be a self-join that is required. I simply demonstrated how it is possible. I will update the Answer in a minute with a proposed solution.

Comment: How do I define the relationship in the follower model.